# ffmpeg overlay watermark only to non-transparent pixels

Tags: ffmpeg, alpha, mov

I have a .mov video with alpha channel and .png watermark. Is it possible to overlay watermark only over the non-transparent pixels of the video using ffmpeg?

Comment: By non-transparent, do you mean only fully non-transparent or even partially non-transparent pixels?

Comment: Only fully non-transparent would be fine, although it would be nice to see both solutions just to improve my knowledge of using and combining ffmpeg filters :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -i image \
       -filter_complex "[0]split[o][a];[a]alphaextract[a];\
                        [o][1]overlay=format=auto[oc];[oc][a]alphamerge" -c:a copy out.mov
```

Choose a codec that preserves alpha like `-c:v png`.